# Delphi, MSExcel, StringGrid

Tags: delphi, excel

Вкратце, содержимое Excel при выполении формы должно загружатся в специально подготовленный SG. В остальных формах программы это работает нормально. А в одной нет. Нажатие на кнопку приводит к ошибке:
"Project New.exe raised exception class EVariantInvalidOpErroe with message 'Invalid variant operation'".
Решил вынести часть проблемного кода в новый проект (а то вдруг в другом месте проблема?) но при компиляции получаю ту же самую ошибку.
Код:

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  excelname:variant;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
ExcelLocation:string;
m,stroka:integer;
begin
GetDir(0,ExcelLocation);
excelname.workbooks.Open(ExcelLocation+'/3.xlsx');
m:=1;
for m:=1 to stroka-1 do
  begin
  stringgrid1.Cells[1,m]:=excelname.range['A'+inttostr(m+1)];
  stringgrid1.Cells[2,m]:=excelname.range['B'+inttostr(m+1)];
  stringgrid1.Cells[3,m]:=excelname.range['C'+inttostr(m+1)];
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
нужно создать сперва объект ексела
Excelname := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
потом попробуйте открыть:
excelname.workbooks.Open(ExcelLocation+'/3.xlsx');
..................................
```